# linear search for number vector in c++

Tags: c++, search, random

I am trying to output 9 random non repeating numbers. This is what I've been trying to do:

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <vector>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    srand(time(0));
    vector<int> v;
    for (int i = 0; i<4; i++) {
        v.push_back(rand() % 10);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j<4; j++) {
        for (int m = j+1; m<4; m++) {
                while (v[j] == v[m]) {
                    v[m] = rand() % 10;
                }
        }
        cout << v[j];
    }
}
```

However, i get repeating numbers often. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Nitpick: Random numbers may very well repeat - in fact if you prevent repeating numbers they are no longer random

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Generating random non repeating number array in C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25878202/generating-random-non-repeating-number-array-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

With a *true* random number generator, the probability of drawing a particular number is not conditional on any previous numbers drawn. I'm sure you've attained the same number twice when rolling dice, for example.

`rand()`, which roughly approximates a true generator, will therefore give you back the same number; perhaps even consecutively: your use of `% 10` further exacerbates this.

If you don't want repeats, then instantiate a vector containing all the numbers you want potentially, then *shuffle* them. `std::shuffle` can help you do that.

See http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle

Comment: This does not solve the OP's specific problem (what's wrong with their code), so it doesn't really help in this specific case. I think it should be posted on the duplicate target instead.

Comment: @user202729: What makes you say that? Do you have further information on the usage requirements?

Comment: @user202729: In your opinion. In mine it's sufficient to point out that the algorithm is defective, and the reason why. Pointing out the specific defects in the implementation is therefore of no benefit. There's no harm in your answering though. As for performance, the bottleneck will be in the `cout`, not Fisher Yates on a set of 10 numbers.

Comment: If your answer only contains that, vote to close as duplicate is (IMO) better. Although... this is slightly better as it explains why does `rand()` generates duplicate numbers. Not sure if it worths it.

Comment: @user202729: But do answer though - there's still time. And I would upvote if I liked it. Voting is never to be taken personally.

Comment: Shubham's answer should cover everything is wrong about OP's code (and so should help the OP to fix their own code). I don't think I need to post another answer.

Answer (score 1):

When `j=0`, you'll be checking it with `m={1, 2, 3}`
But when `j=1`, you'll be checking it with just `m={2, 3}`.

You are not checking it with the `0th` index again. There, you might be getting repetitions.

Also, note to reduce the chances of getting repeated numbers, why not increase the size of random values, let's say maybe `100`.

Please look at the following code to get distinct random values by constantly checking the used values in a `std::set`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <set>

int main() {

    int n = 4;
    std::vector <int> values(n);
    std::set <int> used_values;

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        int temp = rand() % 10;
        while (used_values.find(temp) != used_values.end())
            temp = rand() % 10;
        values[i] = temp;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
        std::cout << values[i] << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Do you have any suggestions on how to fix this problem?

Comment: Yes. Suppose you already have filled `k` distinct values in `n` sized array. Also, these `k` numbers will have to be present in the set. Now to put the `k+1`th index, generate a random number and check if it is present in  the set. If not, then assign it to that position, else repeat.

Comment: i don't clearly understand what you are trying to do

Comment: @matt Please look at the updated answer. I have provided the code to clarify what I was explaining in the comments.

Comment: the updated answer keeps giving me the same random unique number every time i run the program instead of giving me different random unique number every time i run the program

Comment: @matt That's because the numbers are actually pseudo random numbers. You can use the `srand()` to specify a seed value if you wish to.

Comment: @matt You should also read about this here: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/7748374/3160529](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7748374/3160529)