# Why do my random generator doesn't work? C++

Tags: c++, random

I am trying to make a Russian roulette game as my C++ practice, however, I can't figure it out why my random generator doesn't work. Here 's my code:

```
bool shootstatus (int gunsh, int emtysh, bool shs) //gunshell, emptyshell, shotstatus
{
    double shc; //shot chance
    random_device shpo; //shot possibility 
    mt19937 rng(shpo());
    uniform_int_distribution<mt19937::result_type> shpossibility(gunsh,(gunsh+emtysh));
    shc = gunsh/(gunsh+emtysh);
    if(shpossibility(rng)>= shc){
        shs = true;
    } 
    else{
        shs = false;
    }
    return shs;
}
```

I have "cout" the shootstatus, it keeps showing 1.

I am expecting the status would randomly true or false, not constantly true.

Comment: Integer division: `gunsh/(gunsh+emtysh)` is zero.

Comment: You only want to seed the generator from random_device *once*, then use it for the remainder of the program, not (as you're doing here) seed a new generator each time you want a single random number.

Comment: You should use single generator for same responsibility. ex create new generator with random seed  for a game and use that one util end game.

Comment: [You're only supposed to set the seed once](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11943541/12002570)